# Showing that $f(x) = \frac{1-2x^9}{x^5}$ is decreasing for $x>0$

Tags: functions

Hi I was wondering if you could help give some tips in solving this question!
It basically states that 
$$f(x) = \frac{1-2x^9}{x^5}  \qquad \text{for } x>0$$
How do I prove that $f(x)$ is a decreasing function? Thanks

Comment: Do you know about derivatives?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: We get $$f'(x)=-{\frac {8\,{x}^{9}+5}{{x}^{6}}}$$ and this is negative for all $$x>0$$

Answer (score 1):

Without using derivates you can show it this way:
$$f(x) = \frac{1-2x^9}{x^5} = \frac{1}{x^5}-2x^4$$
$$x>0 \implies x \uparrow \implies x^4\uparrow \implies -2x^4\downarrow \tag{1}$$
$$x>0 \implies x \uparrow \implies x^5 \uparrow \implies \frac{1}{x^5} \downarrow \tag{2}$$
$$(1)+(2) \implies \downarrow+\downarrow \implies\downarrow$$

Answer (score 0):

For $y>x>0$, $$f(y)=\frac{1-2y^9}{y^5}<\frac{1-2x^9}{y^5}<\frac{1-2x^9}{x^5}=f(x)$$ because $y^5>x^5$ and $y^9>x^9$ (which implies $1-2y^9<1-2x^9$).
Hence, it is decreasing.